# A simple student examination open-source web software?

Tags: open-source, web-apps, educational, survey

I need a (possibly simple and web-oriented) open-source software to ask a class of students some "open" questions (i.e., with open answers, not a "quiz"...), to be able to evaluate the level of their knowledge about a specific topic.

- It doesn't need to be account-based, I just need to some way link every answered form to a student's name (I trust my students :-)
- For answers evaluation I think to a simple table (".ods", ".csv", ".xml"...) with answers, one row per student
- Exams will be timed, of course, but not so strictly (students will have to answer before next week, for example)

Comment: I did just found this site: https://www.typeform.com, which offers a "core" plan for free, and meets all my requirements... But feel free to provide any further suggestion... :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that [Moodle](https://moodle.org/) is a great option. You can create online courses and give access only to your students. Features such as badges are also available. I have used it as a student and not as a teacher. I cannot answer if it is easy to moderate it, but I think that I am enthusiast about it from the part of studying with it.

On the main site, you will find also the option of a demo without creating any profile.

As for the questions, Moodle supports the following question types:

- Calculated
- Simple Calculated
- Calculated Multichoice
- Description
- Essay
- Matching
- Embedded Answers (Cloze)
- Multiple Choice
- Short-Answer
- Numerical
- True/False
- Third-party question types

Another desirable feature about Moodle is that it has [very few server requirements](http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/Installing_Moodle) It'll work with PHP 5.3+ and smaller installs can get by with 512MB - 1GB of memory).

Answer (score 2):

[Google Forms](https://www.google.com/forms/) is a free service that allows users to create unlimitted number of forms/surveys/questionaires. The form owner and editors are required to use a Google account but respondents are only required to sign-in in case that the number of responses is limited to one by respondent.

Google Apps for Work/Education/Government or the legacy edition could require users from their Google organization to sign-in to allow to answer.

Responses can be downloaded as a CSV file or to submit them automatically to a Google spreadsheet.

Google Forms doesn't include as a built-in feature the option to set a deadline for submitting responses but this could added by using an add-on or a Google Apps Script.

It's worth to say that Google Forms used by a lot of teachers that share tips and tricks about using it in the classroom and that there are some free add-ons designed to be used by teachers like [formLimiter](http://cloudlab.newvisions.org/add-ons/formlimiter) that:

> automatically sets Google Forms to stop accepting responses after a
>   maximum number of responses, at a specific date and time, or when a
>   spreadsheet cell contains a specified value.

Answer (score 0):

I believe QST Quiz/Survey/Test Online - qstonline.ca should meet your needs.
Open source, too many features to describe. Has a GradeBook included, also detailed statistics.